# router navigate doesn't redirect to other page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I would redirect user to another page when he clicks on a datatable row

In **HTML**

```
<p-table  [value]="users" selectionMode="single"  [(selection)]="selectedUser" dataKey="uid" (onRowSelect)="selectedUserDetails($event)" styleClass="tab-result">
```

in TS file

```
selectedUserDetails(userDetails) {
   console.log(userDetails);
   console.log("enterhere"); // is printed on console dev
   this.router.navigate['/userdetails'];
}
```

In **module routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AdministrationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: ResulTabComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "userdetails", component: UserDisplayComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

For information administration route is lazy loaded on this path `http://localhost:4200/administration`

userdetails should be `http://localhost:4200/administration/userdetails`

In **administration component**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My problem is that when clicking I don't get redirected to the `userdetails` page but when I navigate to /userdails from url bar I see the component

Comment: or you could try this one too `this.router.navigateByUrl('/userdetails');`

Comment: try this one `this.router.navigate(['userdetails']);`

Answer (score 11):

You have not called the function, you just try to access a property with name `/userdetails` in the `navigate` property. You missed `()`

```
this.router.navigate(['/userdetails']);
                    ^                ^
```

Comment: It was just , just one more question I get `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'userdetails'
` but I have defined the route

Comment: In the console try to look to which route it is trying to navigate ?

Comment: That error is related with the fact that you did not configured your routes in your application. Please check how to configure application routes in Angular. You have to declare appRoutes, which you declared, then you have to export : export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes); and then import routing in AppModule under imports. Check documentation on how to setup application routes.

Comment: That's what I have made, when I navigate tu userdetails from the browser I land on the component userdetails so route declarations are working, only navigation causes problem

Answer (score 0):

add parentheses "()" and remove slash "/"

```
this.router.navigate(['userdetails']);
```

try routing like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ResulTabComponent },
  { path: "administration/userdetails", component: UserDisplayComponent }
]
```

Comment: Should I delete children attribute on parent path ? ( I have updated routes section in my post )

Comment: Try this once : 

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ResulTabComponent },
{ path: "userdetails", component: UserDisplayComponent }
]

Comment: But I dont' see administration component in your example. userdetails and result tab  should be a it's childs

Comment: add administration before "userdetails" (administration/userdetails)

{ path: "administration/userdetails", component: UserDisplayComponent }